# How does one check if a variable is a sympy expression?

Tags: python, sympy

I wanted to check a python variable is a sympy expression. Its easy to check if its a sympy variable with:

```
isinstance(arg, symbol.Symbol)
```

but I can't find how to do:

```
isinstance(arg, sympy.Expression)
```

is it possible to check if a python variable holds a sympy expression or a variable?

---

as a quick check I did:

```
expr2 = x-y
type(expr2)
<class 'sympy.core.add.Add'>
```

but I don't want to have a giant series if statement clause checking each possible type of maths expression. Seems redundant/silly.

---

It would also nice to be able to detect when a variable is of any type of sympy related thing and then act on it (and then maybe later check if its an expression or something more detailed...)

Answer (score 6):

I think you simply need `sympy.Expr` instead of `sympy.Expression`:

```
In [164]: expr2
Out[164]: x - y

In [165]: type(expr2)
Out[165]: sympy.core.add.Add
```

but if we look at the `__bases__` of this type:

```
In [166]: type(expr2).__bases__
Out[166]: (sympy.core.expr.Expr, sympy.core.operations.AssocOp)
```

And so:

```
In [167]: isinstance(2, sympy.Expr)
Out[167]: False

In [168]: isinstance(x, sympy.Expr)
Out[168]: True

In [169]: isinstance(x-y, sympy.Expr)
Out[169]: True
```